# Getting "Cannot find valid keyframes to interpolate (Breakdowns keyframes are not allowed)" in 2D Blender

Tags: animation, keyframes, error, 2d, interpolation

I'm trying to Interpolate two different keyframes of the same Grease Pencil shape. The second keyframe just rotates & moves the shape around.

I keep getting "Cannot find valid keyframes to interpolate (Breakdowns keyframes are not allowed)" When I use the Interpolate command. I have both Keyframes selected what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In my experience, as soon as you move portions of your grease pencil to a new layer, the Interpolate Sequence function is permanently disabled in your entire project.

Answer (score 3):

Using Blender 3.0.1 I was coming across this issue myself. I would:

- Draw something on frame 1,
- Copy and paste it to another frame (say frame 10)
- Go into *Edit Mode*
- Select both frames then click on the dope sheet and select *Grease Pencil > Interpolate Sequence*

It would give me the error: `Cannot find valid keyframes to interpolate (Breakdowns keyframes are not allowed)`

For me the solution was simple, after you have selected the start and end frame make sure to move the current frame somewhere in between the start and end before selecting *Grease Pencil>Interpolate* from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the auto keying record button in the timeline window, go to the interpolated keyframe, enter edit mode, select all and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd>, move to an empty frame, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>, select this newly created keyframe and move it back to the interpolated one, overwriting it.

If you don't know which is the interpolated keyframe repeat the operation on both.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I have to select the first keyframe first, then the second keyframe (that it morphs into) before clicking on DRAW > Interpolate Sequence.

So when you are putting a box around the keyframes in your sequence you want to shape tween (or morph) make sure you start with the one on the left.

It took me forever to figure this out, but it seems the simple solution to that *error message.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to convert the keys from breakdowns to keyframes:

- Click the first and second keyframes you are trying to interpolate
- Right-click and choose *Keyframe type*, or press  <kbd>R</kbd>
- Click *Keyframe*

It will change those keys to regular keyframes. Then, it would let you interpolate those keyframes (*Grease Pencil > Interpolate Sequence* or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd>).

I think the issue is that Blender won't interpolate breakdowns (keys colored blue on the timeline) which are frames generated between keys that had already been interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when the wrong layer is active.  Select the layer that the start and end keyframes are on (press 'y' or pick it from the layer list).